# Passing the Class<T> in java of a generic list?

Tags: java, generics, gson

I have a method for reading JSON from a service, I'm using Gson to do my serialization and have written the following method using type parameters.

```
public T getDeserializedJSON(Class<T> aClass,String url)
{
    Reader r = getJSONDataAsReader(url);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.fromJson(r, aClass);
}
```

I'm consuming json which returns just an array of a type e.g.

```
[
 { "prop":"value" }
 { "prop":"value" }
]
```

I have a java class which maps to this object let's call it MyClass. However to use my method I need to do this:

```
RestClient<ArrayList<MyClass>> restClient = new RestClient<ArrayList<MyClass>>();
ArrayList<MyClass> results = restClient.getDeserializedJSON(ArrayList<MyClass>.class, url);
```

However, I can't figure out the syntax to do it. Passing just ArrayList.class doesn't work.

So is there a way I can get rid of the Class parameter or how do I get the class of the ArrayList of MyClass?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000227/cannot-select-parameterized-type is a related question and ultimately helped me

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use Bozho's solution, or avoid the creation of a temporary array list by using:

```
Class<List<MyClass>> clazz = (Class) List.class;
```

The only problem with this solution is that you have to suppress the unchecked warning with `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Comment: "The only problem with this solution is that you have to suppress the unchecked warning" - I'm not sure about that. You can as well have this warning, right?

Answer (score 10):

You can't. You'd have to use unsafe cast:

```
Class<List<MyClass>> clazz = 
   (Class<List<MyClass>>) new ArrayList<MyClass>().getClass();
```

Answer (score 7):

As a follow up to this, I found this in the Gson docs.

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
```

Which solves the problem of getting the type safely but the TypeToken class is specific to Gson.

Comment: Ok, but this actually didn't solve the generic problem! I look for something like `Type listType = new TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.getType();` and the generic type `T` is passed as a method paramter like you did in your question

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `SpringFramework` you could use `ParameterizedTypeReference`
as follows:

```
 restClient.getDeserializedJSON(ParameterizedTypeReference<List<MyClass>>(){},url);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar scenario but I have a workaround to use an array instead of ArrayList

```
MyClass[] results = restClient.getDeserializedJSON(MyClass[].class, url);
```

And here what [deserialize](https://github.com/amado-saladino/supernova/blob/master/src/main/java/helpers/RestUtils.java#L57) method does

You can then proceed with list as follows:

```
List<MyClass> r_results= Arrays.stream(results).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how is your requirement, but if you are ok working with array there you can provide as Class: `MyClass[].class`