# Getting a Class instance corresponding to a generic type instantiation

Tags: java, generics, java-7, type-erasure

I've got the following type:

```
public class GenericClass<T> {
    public GenericClass(Class<T> cls) {}
}
```

However, I can't seem to call this when T is itself a generic class:

```
GenericClass<List<String>> g = new GenericClass<>(???);
```

using `List.class` doesn't compile, and `List<String>.class` is invalid syntax. How can I get an instance of a `Class<List<String>>` to pass to the constructor?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797914/passing-the-classt-in-java-of-a-generic-list

Answer (score 2):

Here's an easier solution.. which totally hides the ugliness. The approach here, is to *implicitly bind the result-type* -- and separate that from the passed-in raw Class.

```
public class GenericClass<T> {
    public GenericClass(Class<T> cls) {}

    // static constructor;
    //    - hides unchecked ugliness, & implicitly binds 'nicely typed' to result.
    //
    public static <T>  GenericClass<T> create (Class<? super T> clazz) {
        // ugly cast is hidden in here;  no type checking.
        Class<T> clazz_ = (Class<T>)(Class) clazz;
        return new GenericClass( clazz_);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
GenericClass<List<String>> g = GenericClass.create( List.class);
```

I've bounded the 'passed-in Class' clazz as `? super T` for now, but -- if this too strict -- you can relax the bound & make the parameter just `Class<?> clazz`.

This solution's been tested in my IDE (at least quickly) and seems to work nicely. I'm not sure if, long-term, this is the best way to solve whatever design problem you're having -- but it definitely is the tidiest way to solve your immediate question.

Comment: Looks like there's no way to do it without generating an unchecked exception... :(

Comment: but this is not safe at all. I could pass in `Object.class` for `class` for any `T`.

Comment: It's totally safe.. when you actually *use* the resulting instance/created object. At this time Java _implicitly casts_ the generic to the actual type, as which time a type-check occurs. Type-safety of _actual types_ (not generics) is always preserved within the JVM. This is just a way to sweeten the otherwise-ugly syntax.

Comment: "Unchecked generic type operation"/ "raw type" warnings can be suppressed for this specific method. I have them turned off by default in my IDE, as these warnings are almost always totally spurious & caused in large numbers by pre-1.5 and non-genericized code.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
GenericClass<List<String>> g =
    new GenericClass<>((Class<List<String>>)(Class<?>)ArrayList.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try declaring the constructor as follows

```
public <E extends T> GenericClass(Class<E> cls)
```

Then you can pass List.class, and any child of List, through the constructor.