# cannot select Parameterized Type

Tags: java, spring

I want to create a rest to communicate between server and client.

The constructor given below:

```
public class RestHelper<I, R> {
    public RestHelper(String url, I input, Class<R> output){
        ResponseEntity<R> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, output );
    }
}
```

For normal type, I can do:

```
RestHelper<User, Result> helper = new RestHelper<>(url, user, Result.class);
```

How can I pass a generic type, like:

```
ResultContainData<Boolean>
```

The code below is not working:

```
    ResultContainData<Boolean> result = new ResultContainData<>();
    RestHelper<User, ResultContainData<Boolean>> helper = new RestHelper<>(url, user, (Class<ResultContainData<Boolean>>) ((ParameterizedType) result.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
```

I got a runtime error: cannot cast to ParameterizedType.

Comment: Instead of telling us it "is not working" it would probably be better to post the compiler error. I reckon the problem is with `ResultContainData<Boolean>.class`, right?

Comment: As @John wrote, there is no such thing as **ResultContainData<Boolean>.class**, try **ResultContainData.class**.

Comment: yes, the compile error is cannot select Parameterized Type

Answer (score 14):

I got the solution.

```
ResultContainData<Boolean> result = new ResultContainData<>();
RestHelper<User, ResultContainData<Boolean>> helper = new RestHelper<>(url, user, (Class<ResultContainData<Boolean>>)result.getClass());
```

It's working for me. I am still looking for a better solution.

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit? After you have done so, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 9):

You can only learn the value of I and R by capturing them in a subclass definition - otherwise they are erased at runtime. Ex:

```
class MyStringRestHelper extends RestHelper<String, String> {
```

Then using something like my [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools) you can resolve the values of I and R:

```
Class<?>[] typeArgs = TypeResolver.resolveRawArguments(RestHelper.class, MyStringRestHelper.class);
Class<?> i = typeArgs[0];
Class<?> r = typeArgs[1];
assert i == r == String.class;
```