# What is 'Cannot select from parameterized type' error?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I have

```
public class Assembler extends ResourceAssemblerSupport<User, BeanResource<User> {

    public Assembler() {
        super(UserController.class, BeanResource<User>.class);
    }
}
```

2nd argument to super gives me compile error. Cannot select from parameterized type. Why?

This is the super class

```
public abstract class ResourceAssemblerSupport<T, D extends ResourceSupport> implements ResourceAssembler<T, D> {


public ResourceAssemblerSupport(Class<?> controllerClass, Class<D> resourceType) {}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot select Parameterized Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000227/cannot-select-parameterized-type)